# Handle likes with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a website pizzeria and I wonder if it is possible:

- That each pizza has its own amount of likes.
- I want to track who were the people who gave in like pizza.

For example: A pizza mozzarella, ID 4321, has 3 likes. Anna, Michael and Robert loved this pizza.

I want my software to detect who it was who likes pizza and how many people likes to be able to work so well on these data.

So the question is:

1. Is it possible?
2. Which way I have to go in order to reach this goal?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the Users who liked a Like Button (= Like Button Plugin). One way to achieve this would be to use [og.likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes) and store every Like in your own Database, but that´s pretty complicated and you would have to authorize Users so they can be tracked.

Comment: Then it works as promotion systems in that, for example, the system picks a number x of people to give the awards will be awarded to only those people who likes a page, or due to shared content?

Comment: would still only be possible with user authorization. also, user_likes has to get approved by facebook in order to work for non-admins, and facebook does not approve this permission only for like gating. the only way to implement like gating is to use a page tab.